# How to open album of the public page with appropriate ID in the Facebook application from Android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My question is How to open specific album?
I got the page open, but have no idea about further steps.
Someone already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090992/open-facebook-album-in-facebook-app-android-with-known-user-id-album-id-and-alb).

```
final Intent appIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/144344458913180"));
startActivity(appIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the facebook Graph API documentation, you should make a request as follows:

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{album-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I haven't checked for myself, but if you wanna see the documentation on the albums and how to use them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album